# Second animation

Tags: ios, animation, scale

I have several buttons located at different sites in the view (storyboard), and I want that when I click on each of them to go to a given point,

To do this, I keep their location and initial size by:

```
CGPoint originalCenter1;
CGRect originalsize1;

CGPoint originalCenter2;
CGRect originalsize2;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
originalCenter1 = self.boton1.center;
originalsize1 = self.boton1.frame;

originalCenter2 = self.boton2.center;
originalsize2 = self.boton2.frame;
```

and the IBAction associated with each button, the animation ...

```
-(IBAction)move:(id)sender{

UIButton * pressedbutton = (UIButton*)sender;

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

    CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3.0, 3.0);
    pressedbutton.transform = scale;
    switch(pressedbutton.tag)
    {
        case 0:     
            pressedbutton.center = CGPointMake(784, 340);

            break;
        case 1:
            pressedbutton.center = CGPointMake(784, 340);

            break;
```

When already all have moved, I have a button Refresh that puts me to the initial position.

```
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender{

self.boton1.frame = originalsize1;
self.boton1.center = originalCenter1;
self.boton1.alpha=1;

self.boton2.frame = originalsize2;
self.boton2.center = originalCenter2;
self.boton2.alpha=1;
```

The problem is that the next time that pulse buttons, move to the position shown in the animation but the "scale" effect, doesn't work !!

Any help ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use block try this...

```
- (IBAction)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.view1];
    for (UIView *view in self.view1.subviews) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, tapLocation)) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
                [self setRandomLocationForView:view];
            }];
        }
    }
}


- (void)setRandomLocationForView:(UIView *)view
{
    [view sizeToFit];
    CGRect sinkBounds = CGRectInset(self.view1.bounds, view.frame.size.width/2, view.frame.size.height/2);
    CGFloat x = your location.x;
    CGFloat y = yout location.y;
    view.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```